# ¿Como ordenar descendentemente los registros de mi base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

actualmente me encuentro creando un blog básico con php, y mysql pero a la hora que creo un nuevo post este se muestra de ultimo lugar osea después de los anteriores que he creado, pero me gustaría que este apareciese de primer lugar por ser el mas reciente y así sucesivamente.

Aqui les muestro una imagen de como se encuentra actualmente, lo que me gustaria es que las nuevas publicaciones se muestren de primer lugar, en este caso 'Prueba #3' fue la publicación mas reciente pero se muestra de ultimo lugar. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

[image: imagen]

CODIGO: index.php

```
<div class="cuadro">
        <h1 class="mensaje">Acciones Recientes</h1>
                <h3 class="subtitulos">POSTS AGREGADOS</h3>
                <div class="capitulos-rc">
              <?php foreach ($posts as $key => $post): ?>
             <tr class="capitulos-tr">
              <td><?php echo $key +1; ?></td>
              <td><?php echo $post['title']; ?></td>
            </tr><br>
              <?php endforeach; ?>
                </div>
        </div>
```

CODIGO: posts.php

```
if (isset($_POST['add-post'])) {
    $_POST['topic_id']=serialize($_POST['topic_id']);
    $errors = validatePost($_POST);
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
        unset($_POST['add-post']);
        $post_id = create($table, $_POST);
        $_SESSION['message'] = '¡Anime creado correctamente!';
        $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
        header('location: ../../admin/posts/index.php');
        exit();
    } else {
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $body = $_POST['body'];
        $topic = $_POST['topic_id']; 
    }
}
```

CODIGO: db.php

```
function selectAll($table, $conditions = [])
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id";
    if (empty($conditions)) {
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;    
    } else {
        // $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table WHERE username='ElVictox' AND admin=1";
        
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";
                
            } else {
                $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        $values = array_values($conditions);
        $types = str_repeat('s', count($values));
        $stmt->bind_param($types, $values);
        $stmt->execute();
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        return $records;
    }
}



function selectOne($table, $conditions)
{
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ";

        $i = 0;
                foreach ($conditions as $key => $value) {
            if ($i === 0){
                $sql = $sql . " WHERE $key=?";

            } else {
               $sql = $sql . " AND $key=?"; 
            }
            $i++;
        }
        $sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";
        $sql = $sql . " LIMIT 1";
        $stmt = executeQuery($sql, $conditions);
        $records = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_assoc();
        return $records;
    }
```

TABLA BASE DE DATOS:
[image: IMAGEN]

Comment: Ya lo intente, pero sigue estando igual @BetaM

Comment: Sí ya lo cambie pero sigue estando igual, estoy editando la pregunta

Comment: Lo acabo de intentar pero sigue de la misma manera. @BetaM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo con tu estructura de base de datos que presentas puedes ordenar la consulta por el **id**, ya que es autoincrementable o bien por el campo **created_at** porqué en teoría la fecha para las nuevas entradas serán mas recientes que las de las anteriores; sólo cuidando que se ordene en forma descendente para que muestre primero el último insertado.

Tu consulta quedaría de la siguiente manera

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM $table ORDER BY id DESC"; // DESC -> Descendente
```

Puesto que a cómo muestras en el código que presentas, los condicionales se construyen de manera dinámica, procura que el **[ORDER BY](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/order-by.php) id DESC** esté al final. Tal que tengas una consulta como la siguiente:

```php
$sql = = "SELECT * FROM $table";

// Agregas los WHERE y AND según sea requerido
... 

$sql = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
...
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me funciono correctamente!!.